# PayPal button with custom amount

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to add a PayPal 'Buy Now' button to my website.  Because the price of my product is customer per order I need to pass in custom amount which is pulled in by the variable `{{ order.invoiceValue }}`.  My code snippet is below, but it does not seem to be recognized by PayPal (see screenshot below).  Any help would be appreciated!

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXYYYZZZ">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="service@mycompany.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{ order.invoiceValue }}">
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">


  <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  <img alt="" border="0"`enter code here` src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add the code {{ order.invoiceValue }}. Instead, just leave the value as a blank. When your customers put the amount, the price it will be passed to PP.